# running clock in zenity menu

Tags: zenity

I have created a menu by
`... zenity --title="ABC" --text="Date-'date +%d%m%Y-%T'" --list --radiolist --column="select" --column="option" FALSE "1" FALSE "2" FALSE "3"` Menu showing date with time when I entered in menu. I was trying to get running clock by watch -t -n 1 date +%T. When I use this command system is not giving any output. Is it possible to show running time in zenity menu by any other way?.

Comment: I don't think you can do that (a menu that shows the real time) with `zenity`. You need tools like [`pyGObject`](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between - and t remove this and it should work fine:

```
watch -t -n 1 date +%T
```

Comment: Ni it does not work

Comment: Please somebody help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with zenity alone in the general case. Using X11 tools you could run a clock in the title bar of your zenity dialog window. Below I used xdotool to find the correct window and set the text in the title bar

```
date_time=$(date +%d/%m/%Y\ %T)
new_date_time=$(date +%d/%m/%Y\ %T)

zenity --title "${date_time}" --display=:0 \
       --text="Running clock in window title bar" --list --radiolist \
       --column="select" --column="option" FALSE "1" FALSE "2" FALSE "3" &

while true
do
  sleep 1
  new_date_time=$(date +%d/%m/%Y\ %T)
  xdotool search --name "${date_time}" set_window --name "${new_date_time}"
  date_time="${new_date_time}"
done
```